# como usar window.innerWidth dentro de computed property - NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

estou trabalhando em um projeto vue.js/nuxt.js, onde eu preciso determinar estilos dentro do computed property e aplicar em uma `div` com base no tamanho da tela, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<template>
  <div :style="css"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    css () {
      let width = window.innerWidth

      // ... mobile { ... styles }
      // ... desktop { ... styles }

      // ... if width is less than 700, return mobile
      // ... if width greater than 700, return desktop
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

isso não da certo, gera um erro `windows is note defined`

no Nuxt.js, o `window` só estará disponível dentro do `mounted`, que é gancho de ciclo de vida onde a tela já foi renderizada, o que faz total sentido.

Eu poderia colocar toda essa lógica de estilo dentro de um método e chamar no mounted, ou colocar diretamente no mounted e aplicar na `div`, o problema é que o estilo será aplicado com um certo `delay` depois que a página é montada.

Então como posso saber o tamanho da largura interna da página dentro do computed property?

Comment: Um arquivo `.vue` tem 3 seções, `<template>`, `<script>` e `<style>`. Não seria melhor você adicionar um CSS com media queries dentro  da tag `<style>`? Não entendi porque você está estilizando no JS.

Comment: @fernandosavio, nesse caso não, pois se trata de um componente reutilizável, logo a estilização será dinâmica e terá um certo nível de complexidade a ponto de que só atribuir uma classe CSS não resolveria o problema, precisar ser feita com com script.

Comment: Entendi, acredito que deve ter um jeito melhor de fazer isso mas [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47219938/1284458) demonstra uma maneira de fazer isso..

Comment: O próprio Evan You [aconselha a fazer isso](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1915) dentro dos lifecycle hooks.. então não sei se tem jeito melhor de fazer

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fernandosavio/pen/wVvVdK?editors=1010) que fiz, acredito que te ajude. Seria uma boa ideia você dar um debounce ou um throttle no evento de resize para não sobre carregar o cliente.

Comment: @fernandosavio, desde já fico imenso grato por estar me ajudando, mas o código que você fez, não funcionará no Nuxt.js `largura: window.innerWidth,` iria gerar `windows is not defined` como eu falei na minha questão, o `window` só estará disponível a partir do `mounted`

Comment: O valor inicial pode ser qualquer um.. você pode atribuir esse valor no mounted mesmo. Eu só coloquei direto por praticidade, você precisa adaptar o código para seu caso

Comment: @fernandosavio, não posso mexer com `mounted`, como eu disse na minha questão, irá aplicar o estilo com certo delay.. eu já testei, você pode testar também.. coloca alguma div com largura e altura full, e no `mounted` você aplica um background a essa div, quando vc carregar a página no browser, ou ficar dando F5, perceberá que a página carrega por inteira, pra depois aplicar a a cor de fundo, isso é horrível.

Comment: @fernandosavio, estou fazendo um componente de Grid Layout, então imagina, a página carregar toda quebrada, pra só depois se ajustar? não dá, precisa ter o estilo definido antes de chegar ao `mounted`

Comment: É o preço por usar JS para estilizar. Mas OK, vou acompanhar a pergunta pra ver se alguém que entenda tenha uma saída. Boa sorte